# How to handle response of the REST call in ember.js-data

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I've setup Ember with a RESTAdapter in order to retrieve my models via a RESTfull API.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({ 
    url : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
    // In order to allow cross domain requests
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        jQuery.ajax(url)

        },
    }),
});

App.File = DS.Model.extend({
    content: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

In my Route I want a specific file via a REST call and pass it to my template.

```
 App.FilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            var file = App.File.find("49898c14b49eab87597d3195b500107e")
            console.log(file)
            return file  
        }
    });
```

But Ember serves me a blank page when I'm return the File. When I return a random string my template will load.

The Network tab of Chromiums developer tools shows me the response of the call to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/files/49898c14b49eab87597d3195b500107e`:
 `{"file": {"content": null, "name": "Titl"}}`
That is the response I expected. But Ember wraps it in an complex object:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The "complex" object is a DS.Model instance. In your case, it should be a App.File.

You can access the retrieved value by calling `.get('name')` on this object for example.

Also, `App.FilesRoute` expects you to return an array, not a single instance.